# Mail clients for mobile devices for connecting to ADFS configured Office 365 mail

Tags: adfs, microsoft-office-365, email

Any of you  aware of any mail clients for mobile devices for connecting to Office 365 domains which are configured to single sign on through ADFS.

Outlook.com client for android this doesnt seem to support ADFS.

[Microsoft Office Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.officehub)
  this supports adfs login but this is not a mail client.

Answer (score 1):

why are you wanting to use the Outlook.com client with Office 365?

Just use the built-in mail client within Android and configure it the same way as any Exchange client (in this case using your ADFS credentials):

**Set up Microsoft Exchange email on an Android**

1. From the Applications menu, select Email. This application may be named Mail on some versions of Android.
2. Type your full email address, for example tony@contoso.com, and your password, and then select Next.
3. Select Exchange account. This option may be named Exchange ActiveSync on some versions of Android.
4. Enter the following account information and select Next.
5. Domain\Username Type your full email address in this box. If Domain and Username are separate text boxes in your version of Android, leave the Domain box empty and type your full email address in the Username box.

   Note:    On some versions of Android, you must use the domain\username format. For example, if your email address is tony@contoso.com, type contoso.com\tony@contoso.com. Your username is your full email address.

   Password: Use the password that you use to access your account.

   Exchange Server Use the address of your Exchange server. If you’re connecting to your Office 365 email, use outlook.office365.com for your server name.

Other mobile devices: [Phone and tablet setup reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Phone-and-tablet-setup-reference-6777abf4-0430-4392-bea0-9c169d85b14d?CTT=5&origin=HA102823196&CorrelationId=3a31f3a2-5396-4649-836a-a299d4357b44&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)